# I need help in designing my C++ Console application

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, application-design

I have a task to complete. 
There are two types of csv files `4000+` both related to each other.
2 types are:
1. Country2.csv
2. Security_Name.csv
Contents of `Country2.csv`:
`Company Name;Security Name;;;;Final NOS;Final FFR`
Contents of `Security_Name.csv`:
`Date;Close Price;Volume`

There are multiple countries and for each country multiple security files
Now I need to **READ** them do some **CALCULATION** and then **WRITE** the output in another files

1. **READ** 
   Read both the file Country 2.csv and Security.csv and extract all the data from them.
   For example : 
   Read France 2.csv, extract `Security_Name, Final NOS, Final FFR`
   Then Read Security.csv(which matches the `Security_Name`) and extract
    `Date, Close Price, Volume`
2. **Calculation**
   Calculations are basically finding Median of the values extracted which is quite simple.
   For Example: 
       Monthly Median Traded Values 
       Daily Traded Value of a Security ... and so on
3. **Write**
   Based on the month I need to sort the output in two different file with following formats:
   If Month % 3 = 0
   Save It as MONTH_NAME.csv in following format:
   `Security name; 12-month indicator; 3-month indicator; FOT`
   Else
   Save It as MONTH_NAME.csv in following format:
   `Security Name; Monthly Median Traded Value Ratio; Number of days Volume > 0`

My question is how do I design my application in such a way that it is maintainable and the flow of data throughout the execution is seamless?

Comment: So...you *really* shouldn't be asking the last question.  That's something you can google.  You've told us nothing about the **calculation** or the **output**.  Maybe you'd like some help around designing your input data/process?  A person could almost attempt to answer/help with that (at a high level), and it could be considered one question.  I would rewrite your question to be more specific and THEN add the `C++` tag if that's the language you're planning on using.

Comment: @zzxyz I have edited the question, Can you see if makes more sense now?

Comment: Sure...it does.  It's still too broad for StackOverflow, but I can at least help you get started.

Comment: Sure, Thanks @zzxyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first thing.  Based on the kind of data you are looking to generate, I would probably be looking at moving this data to a SQL db if at all possible.  This is "one SQL query" kind of stuff.  And *far* more maintainable than C++ that generates CSV files from CSV files.

Barring that, I would probably look at using `datamash` and/or `perl`.  On a Windows platform, you could do this through Cygwin or WSL.  Probably less maintainable, but so much easier it's not too much of an issue.

That said, if you're looking for something *moderately* maintainable, C++ could work.  The first thing I would do is design my input classes.  Data-centric, but it can work.  It sounds like you could have a `Country` class, a `Security` class, and a `SecurityClose` class...or something along those lines.  You can think about whether a Security class should contain a collection of `SecurityClose`es (data), or whether the data should just be "loose" and reference the `Security` it belongs to.  Same with the Country->Security relationship.

Once you've decided how all that's going to look, you want something (likely a function) that can `tokenize` a CSV line.  So `"1,2,3"` gets turned into a `vector<string>` with the contents `"1"` `"2"` `"3"`.  Then, each of your input classes should have a constructor or initializer that takes a `vector<string>` and populates itself.  You might need to pass higher level data along too.  Like the filename if you want the security data to know which security it belongs to..

That's basically most of the battle there.  Once you've pulled your data into sensibly organized classes, the rest should come more easily.  And if you run into bumps, hopefully you can ask *specific* design or implementation questions from there.

Comment: Putting the data in the database is not an option for me here, but your explanation did help me in choosing my data classes and how I would be able to relate those classes. Thanks.

Comment: @ThePashupatee I’m glad it helped at least a little!